# Reporting Services - Find value in a group

Tags: reporting-services, grouping, aggregate-functions

I have a column with three possible values:

-1, 0 and any value greater than 0.

In each group, I must verify if ALL values are equal to -1 and if present ALMOST 0 value.
Is it possible?

I tried to solve it in this way:

```
=IIf(CountDistinct(Fields!Flag_09.Value,"Group1") = CountRows("Group1")
     And First(Fields!Flag_09.Value = "-1"), "-",
     [ ???? ])
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "if present ALMOST 0 value", could you explain further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want to see if all the detail rows in a group are -1 and then do something. Fortunately your data allows a very simple solution:

```
=IIF(CountRows("Group1") = 0 - SUM(Fields!MyField.Value), "-", "They aren't all -1")
```

That is, if the number of rows is equal to the negative of the sum of this field, then all the fields have -1 in them.